# Spring JPA CriteriaQuery child entity columns

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, aggregate-functions, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to make some dynamic mechanism to fetch data from db using criteria query based on given class, specification, select columns, aggregated columns and group by columns.

Here's the code which is working fine:

```
    public <T> List<T> findDataByConfiguration(Specification<T> specification, 
        Class clazz, List<String> selectColumns, 
        List<String> aggregationColumns, List<String> groupByColumns) {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = this.entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Tuple> query = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();
        Root<T> root = query.from(clazz);

        List<Selection<?>> multiSelectColumns = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : selectColumns) {
            multiSelectColumns.add(root.get(s).alias(s));
        }

        for (String s : aggregationColumns) {
            multiSelectColumns.add(criteriaBuilder.sum(root.get(s)).alias(s));
        }

        List<Expression<?>> groupByColumnsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : groupByColumns) {
            groupByColumnsList.add(root.get(s));
        }

        query.groupBy(groupByColumnsList);
        query.multiselect(multiSelectColumns);
        query.where(specification.toPredicate(root, query, criteriaBuilder));

        List<Tuple> resultList = this.entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();

        // resultList processing
    }
```

This code is working fine when when I want to fetch data of flat entity class.
But when I am trying to add child entiti'es field in select/aggregate/group by then it's throwing an error:

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [child.id] on this ManagedType [com.sup.as.data.entity.co.Annual]**

```
// annotations
public class Annual {
    private Long id;
    private String fp;
    private ID iDetails;
    // getter-setter
}

public class ID {
    private Long id;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    // getter-setter

    public String giveMeData() {
        if(id != null && amount != null) {
            return "FILED";
        } else {
            return "NOT FILED";
        }
    }
}
```

now suppose I want field **Annual.id, Annual.fp, SUM(Annual.iDetails.amount), Annual.iDetails.giveMeData**

So is it possible to add child entities columns in select/aggregate/group by ?
If anyone have done this type of solution then please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

If some of column names are dot-separated (for instance, `child.id`) you have to use `root.get("child").get("id")` instead of `root.get("child.id")`

You need method like this

```
private Path<Object> getPath(Root<?> root, String columnPath) {

    if(!columnPath.contains(".")) {
       return root.get(columnPath);
    }

    String[] levels = columnPath.split(".");  
    Path<T> path = root;
    for(String level : levels) {
        path = path.get(level);
    }

    return path;
}
```

Then use it for `selectColumns`, `aggregationColumns` and `groupByColumns` this way

```
for (String s : selectColumns) {
   multiSelectColumns.add(getPath(root, s).alias(s));
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to invoke method in this ? suppose I am have 2 fields and there's 1 method which uses existing 2 fields and return some results..

Comment: 1 more issue is that if I will fetch child column and will set value to parent then child is not initialized it will not set value of child field.

Comment: This is pretty hard to understand without context. Let you give me an example

Comment: added in question. class structure and field to be fetched

Comment: `Annual.iDetails.giveMeData` is not a field but method. Here is not allowed to use `root.("iDetails").get("giveMeData")`

Comment: Yes my first comment is regarding that method data fetch.

Comment: I misunderstood the question. You can only get database column values as query result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214908/discussion-between-alex-valuiskyi-and-user3145373-).

Comment: Yes but if I want SUM(Annual.iDetails.amount) or Annual.iDetails.id just  then it will not work as in Annual iDetails is not initialized.